# Can I use my behringer umc202hd as a preamp for my mixer?

Tags: voice, recording, audio, mixer

I currently have a behringer umc202hd audio interface and I'm looking to upgrade to a usb mixer (behringer xenyx q802usb). I'm doing this to give myself more mic inputs however, I don't want to waste my audio interface and I don't want to spend much money on a mixer. So, my question is can I use the audio interface's 1/4 inch outputs to lead in to the mixers line in to give myself in theory 2 more mic inputs?

Comment: Bear in mind that having more mic inputs from a mixer doesn't mean that you can record from them all simultaneously as individual tracks on the computer; If you want more inputs for computer recording purposes, the straightforward move is to buy an interface with more inputs.

Comment: I'll look into some other mixers but do you think that this idea would possibly work? Even if it doesn't mean getting more individual tracks.

Comment: Im not exactly an expert on anything like this and I most likely won't be doing any complicated sound editing or stuff like that so I don't think that will matter too much. I mean correct me if you think I would just be better off future proofing.

Comment: It's just that typically when you use a computer to record, you do your mixing inside the computer, and an external mixer often isn't necessary. It might be useful if you wanted to, say, mic up a drum kit, mix that outside the computer, and send that in to the computer as a stereo track. But usually, if you need more inputs, it's useful to have those as separate channels going into the computer so that you can then mix them separately. What will you be using all the new mic inputs for? e.g. will you be getting a bunch of singers in singing together?

Comment: And... if you don't want to record the separate inputs to separate tracks, why not just buy a non-USB mixer and use it with your existing interface?

Comment: Actually, thats exactly why i'm doing it. I have a youtube channel for a few of my friends and I who enjoy singing. I have an at2020 that would go into the 1st mic input on the mixer, a neewer nw-800 that would go into the 2nd mic input. and then a pair of neewer dynamic microphones that I wanted to run through the audio interface and into the line in on channel 3/4 on the mixer (if possible).The dynamic mics would be used for background vocals, the 2020 for the soloist/soloists, and the bm-800 being used to mic a piano.

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is can I use the audio interface's 1/4 inch outputs to lead in to the mixers line in

Actually, with that interface, my guess is that you probably could by using the direct monitor switch (i.e. not having the audio go in and out of the computer). It's quite a sneaky idea! It would be a slightly odd setup though and I would imagine you're slightly increasing the chance of strange noises and hums creeping in by having two devices connected to the same USB bus and also connected to each other through an analogue connection.

> to give myself in theory 2 more mic inputs?

As per our conversation in the comments - it depends what you mean. It gives you a place to plug 2 more mics in, but even if it worked, you'd still only be able to record the mix of those mics, rather than the individual tracks - which might be fine, until you realise you want the individual tracks!

If possible, you might want to look at selling the umc202hd and getting something with more inputs like the UMC404HD (which would give you 4 individually-mixable inputs) or the UMC1820 if you really need a lot of inputs.

If you really don't think you'll need to mix the tracks separately in the computer and you are otherwise happy with the UMC202HD, I'd suggest perhaps looking for a nice second hand analogue-only mixer (with no USB) and using that with your existing interface.

Comment: Thanks man! Im looking at the xenyx 1202 now and It actually costs quite a bit less (considering its not usb that makes sense). And then as for how to connect it to the interface would i just run the line out from the mixer straight into the combo jacks on the interface with 1/4 inch to 1/4 inch cables?